# 2 exact same boxes with one having double ram - is it really that much better?

Tags: memory, central-processing-unit

With these two servers, is the 32gb ram server that much better than the 16?  Having the same cpu, would the server first bottleneck at the cpu before the extra 16gb ram comes into play? Or am I completely wrong?

Intel® Core™i7-2600 Quadcore w/Hyper-Threading
16 GB DDR3 RAM
2 x 3 TB SATA 6 Gb/s HDD 7200 rpm Software- RAID 1

Intel® Core™i7-2600 Quadcore w/Hyper-Threading
32 GB DDR3 RAM
2 x 3 TB SATA 6 Gb/s HDD 7200 rpm Software- RAID 1

Comment: It really depends on what the servers are used for

Comment: "I like pepperoni pizza. Should I buy a small one or a large one? Would large be better for me?"

Comment: dude, don't be an frakking a hole.  It is a legitimate question.

Comment: It depends entirely on your workload. If you are memory-bound, then adding more memory will make a difference. If you're CPU-bound or IO-bound then it won't really help (unless you can use it to increase the size of your cache).

Comment: @joe: It's really not a legitimate question for this site. There is way too little information about the workload for starters. Please take a look at [Gorilla V Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/), [Lets Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and the [faq] for an insight as to why.

Comment: Did I ask opinions on who thought what was better?  No.  I asked , "Having the same cpu, would the server first bottleneck at the cpu before the extra 16gb ram comes into play?"  That is a very legitimate question.  I'm sorry, but you are wrong for closing this.

Comment: Joe, sorry, you're wrong here. Which server is more appropriate for your environment is completely dependent on what will be running on it. While having extra memory will rarely be a bad thing, we know that cost is a consideration as well. You just need to do some real load testing of your application to see if it would benefit from the extra memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you answer this?

Would I put the two into a failover pair?  No.  What if you were on the 32G server as master and it failed over?  Is that the point where you'd want to find out that 16G wasn't enough?

Don't cheat, don't skimp.  If it really matters, put the money behind it.  If money matters more than uptime, take the 16G out of the first server and sell it off.  If you are still up, that 16G didn't matter anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your real answer, and not just pompous jabber to demean the people who don't know as much.